# DisplayNameFor Class Inside Class MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller, data-annotations

Consider I have 2 class for example:

```
Class ClsStudent
   Public Id As System.Nullable(Of Integer)

   <Required(AllowEmptyStrings:=False)> _
   <StringLength(45, ErrorMessage:="Name must not exceed 45 characters.")> _
   <Display(Name:="Full Name", Description:="Student full name.")> _
   Public Name As String = ""
End Class

Class Voila
   Public Student As ClsStudent
   Public Status As Boolean
End Class
```

I pass the voila to the view and would like to access the DisplayNameFor of the student name in the view:

```
@Html.DisplayNameFor(Function(m) m.Student.Name)
```

But it shows the field name : "Name" instead of the display name attribute that has been assigned to it "Full Name".

What's wrong with my code?

Comment: In MVC we bind our view with model so we can write code in that way also  @Html.DisplayNameFor(model=>model.Student.Name)  It will display as  "Full Name"

Answer (score 0):

Okay...after wasting few hours I just figured out I miss to put "property" to the property name. It should be "Public Property Name As String = ''" instead of "Public Name As String = ''". Fewss.....:(((